# how do I make `\mathabx` work

Tags: xetex, packages, mathabx

How do I make `\mathabx` below work ? Without `\mathabx` it works fine
but **with it** it gives the error copied below. There are probably some clashes.
It should give at `\ggg` this >> [here](https://math.uoregon.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/compsymb-1qyb3zd.pdf) on page 49, and **not** >>> as it gives when `\mathabx` is commented. Probably the order of loading packages matters.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\usepackage{mathabx} % HERE

%\usepackage{xypic}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
%\usepackage{mypackage}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\pullbackcorner}[1][dl]{\save*!/#1-1pc/#1:(1,-1)@^{|-}\restore}


\usepackage{babyloniannum}

\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]


\MakeRobust\babyloniannum
%\MakeRobust\hgnum
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
$\ggg$

$\Game$
\underline{motto:}{ každý den $\pm$ nový princip }\hfill{$\square$}
\bigskip
\bigskip
  rozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého



%\demoletter{O}\demoletter{n}\demoletter{e}
%\demoletter{l}\demoletter{i}\demoletter{n}\demoletter{e}\demoletter{.}




  teorie mn
\end{document}
```

ERROR WITH `\mathabx`------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Command Line:   D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "ideje27.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(ideje27.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/accents\accents.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/tikz-cd\tikz-cd.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-xetex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
 (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.
code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.te
x)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.cod
e.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithme
tics.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code
.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.
tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.co
de.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.cod
e.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.
tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
 (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
)) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.cod
e.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlib
rarytopaths.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/tikz-cd\tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlib
rarymatrix.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlib
raryquotes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryarrows.meta.code
.tex))) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/mathabx\mathabx.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/mathabx\mathabx.dcl

! LaTeX Error: Command `\ring' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.191 ...athAccent{\ring}          {0}{mathb}{"38}
                                                  
? 

! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.191 ...athAccent{\ring}          {0}{mathb}{"38}
                                                  


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: What else do you need from `mathabx`?

Answer (score 2):

You should load `accents` after `mathabx`. Omit `amssymb`, because `mathabx` already provides the symbols.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx} % HERE
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

$\ggg$

$\Game$
\underline{motto:} každý den $\pm$ nový princip\hfill{$\square$}

\end{document}
```

I omitted the irrelevant parts, including `babyloniannum` that's not distributed with TeX Live.